# Show/hide HTML divs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

My HTML code has the following structure:

```
<a class='card'...<a/>
<div id = "divone" class="card__background" ... </div>
```

with four respective cards.

When one of the divs with class='card' is clicked. The JavaScript code is supposed to hide the 'class="card__background" inside the other class='card' divs. I already have a script code that doesn't work.

Why would that be?

I am looking to fix my JavaScript code to make it work

```js
function imagechange(divid) {
  var x = document.getElementById(divid);
  if (x == "divone") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    divtwo.style.display = 'none';
    divthree.style.display = 'none';
    divfour.style.display = 'none';
  } else if (x == "divtwo";) {
    x.style.display = "block";
    divone.style.display = 'none';
    divthree.style.display = 'none';
    divfour.style.display = 'none';
  } else if (x == "divthree";) {
    x.style.display = "block";
    divone.style.display = 'none';
    divtwo.style.display = 'none';
    divfour.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
    divone.style.display = 'none';
    divtwo.style.display = 'none';
    divthree.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  --background-dark: #2d3548;
  --text-light: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  --text-lighter: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  --spacing-s: 8px;
  --spacing-m: 16px;
  --spacing-l: 24px;
  --spacing-xl: 32px;
  --spacing-xxl: 64px;
  --width-container: 1200px;
}

* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-section {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-image: linear-gradient(15deg, #0f4667 0%, #2a6973 150%);
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: var(--spacing-xxl) var(--spacing-l);
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: var(--spacing-l);
  grid-row-gap: var(--spacing-l);
  max-width: var(--width-container);
  width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 540px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media(min-width: 960px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}

.card {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.card:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 150%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card__background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: var(--spacing-l);
  bottom: 0;
  filter: brightness(0.75) saturate(1.2) contrast(0.85);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: center;
  trsnsform: scale(1) translateZ(0);
  transition: filter 200ms linear, transform 200ms linear;
}

.card:hover .card__background {
  transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
}

.card-grid:hover>.card:not(:hover) .card__background {
  filter: brightness(0.5) saturate(0) contrast(1.2) blur(20px);
}

.card__content {
  left: 0;
  padding: var(--spacing-l);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.card__category {
  color: var(--text-light);
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-bottom: var(--spacing-s);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.card__heading {
  color: var(--text-lighter);
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  line-height: 1.4;
  word-spacing: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <center>
    <h1>My Favorite Things</h1>
    <h2>Click on one to get started</h2>
  </center>
  <section class="hero-section">
    <div class="card-grid">
      <a class="card" onclick="imagechange('divone')" href="#">
        <div id="divone" class="card__background" style="background-image: url(photo-one.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <p class="card__category">FAV #1</p>
          <h3 class="card__heading">Photo</h3>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a class="card" onclick="imagechange('divtwo')" href="#">
        <div id="divtwo" class="card__background" style="background-image: url(photo-two.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <p class="card__category">FAV #2</p>
          <h3 class="card__heading">Drawing</h3>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a class="card" onclick="imagechange('divthree')" href="#">
        <div id="divthree" class="card__background" style="background-image: url(photo-three.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <p class="card__category">FAV #3</p>
          <h3 class="card__heading">Sports & Lifting</h3>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a class="card" onclick="imagechange('divfour')" href="#">
        <div id="divfour" class="card__background" style="background-image: url(photo-four.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="card__content">
          <p class="card__category">FAV #4</p>
          <h3 class="card__heading">Anime & Peaky Blinders</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div>
  </section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use var `x = document.getElementById(divid);` you are getting an object. So your condition never going to be true.

If you want to check the id just change condition to:

```js
function imagechange(divid) {
  const x = document.getElementById(divid)
  const id = x.id

  if (id === 'divone') {
    x.style.display = 'block'
    divtwo.style.display = 'none'
    divthree.style.display = 'none'
    divfour.style.display = 'none'
  } 
  else if (id === 'divtwo') {
    x.style.display = 'block'
    divone.style.display = 'none'
    divthree.style.display = 'none'
    divfour.style.display = 'none'
  }  
  else if (id === 'divthree') {
    x.style.display = 'block'
    divone.style.display = 'none'
    divtwo.style.display = 'none'
    divfour.style.display = 'none'
  }  
  else {
    x.style.display = 'block'
    divone.style.display = 'none'
    divtwo.style.display = 'none'
    divthree.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

Comment: `const id = x.id` makes no sense. You already have the `id`, it's `divid`.

Comment: I am trying to explain why original x is not an string, it is only an example. Passing id by param when u have the event with the target is better but i am not making a refactor.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Please avoid using scripts straight in your HTML, this leads to unorganized code, with a horrible structure, and pessible for maintence.

2 -  I deleted the code in the ***script*** tags and in place put

```
<script src="./site.js"></script>
```

In the same folder. Create a js file correspondent to the name of your html, in this case I used '*site.js*'.

3- Use this code in your '*site.js*' file.

```
var cards = ["card1", "card2", "card3", "card4"]
var divs = ["div1", "div2", "div3", "div4"]

cards.forEach(function (card, i){
    document.getElementById(card).addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display = 'block'
    for (let j in divs){
        if (i != j)  document.getElementById(divs[j]).style.display = 'none'
    }
  })
})
```

4 - Delete all the ***onclick="imagechange()"*** of your card class tags and add id for them.

5 - Your HTML will be like this:

```
<body>
  <center> 
   <h1>My Favorite Things</h1>
   <h2>Click on one to get started</h2>
  </center>
<section class="hero-section">
 <div class="card-grid">
   <a id = "card1" class="card" href="#">
     <div id = "div1" class="card__background" style="background-image: url(photo-one.jpg)"></div>
     <div class="card__content">
       <p class="card__category">FAV #1</p>
       <h3 class="card__heading">Photo</h3>
     </div>
   </a>
   
   <a id = "card2" class="card" href="#">
     <div id = "div2" class="card__background" style="background-image: url(photo-two.jpg)"></div>
     <div class="card__content">
       <p class="card__category">FAV #2</p>
       <h3 class="card__heading">Drawing</h3>
     </div>
   </a>
   
   <a id = "card3" class="card" href="#">
     <div id = "div3" class="card__background" style="background-image: url(photo-three.jpg)"></div>
     <div class="card__content">
       <p class="card__category">FAV #3</p>
       <h3 class="card__heading">Sports & Lifting</h3>
     </div>
   </a>
   
   <a id = "card4" class="card" href="#">
     <div id = "div4" class="card__background" style="background-image: url(photo-four.jpg)"></div>
     <div class="card__content">
       <p class="card__category">FAV #4</p>
       <h3 class="card__heading">Anime & Peaky Blinders</h3>
     </div>
   </a>
 <div>
</section>
<script src="./site.js"></script>
</body>
```